# git bash help command fails to open html

Tags: git, bash

Git version 1.9.2-preview20140411 
Windows 8.1

Command entered:

> $ git help clear

Error message received:

> trace: built-in: git 'help' 'clear' 
>   Launching default browser to display HTML ...
>   fatal: failed to launch browser for C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/doc/git/html//gitclear.html

Problem reproduced by:
`$ git help <cmd>` or `$ git <cmd> --help`

Expected Solution:
The help file is launched.

I checked out https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=445 but I'm not sure as to 
1. Whether it really applies to my problem
2. What the actual proposed solution is

New to git and to coding in general - hence might be a bit slow

Comment: Weird, same thing happens with my git. I've never tried that command before.

Comment: `clear` is not a git command.

Comment: @gravetii you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that because `clear` is not a `git` command. Try the same with `status` for example to see the difference.

Comment: `status` works. However commmands like `mkdir` and `touch` don't work. Are those not legit `git` commands either?

Comment: They are unix commands, not git. You can look them up using `man mkdir` etc.